# Is it possible to set XCUITest timeout?

Tags: swift, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing, xcuitest

The per-test timeout in XCUITest is too short and timesout while I am still examining the stack.  Is it possible to increase that?

BrowerStack apparently has one: https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/xcuitest/timeouts. But is there a native means?

Comment: Are you setting a breakpoint in the application code and examining the stack there?

Comment: Yes.  And it timeout after about 2 minutes.

Comment: That's something in your IDE or app - I've held debug sessions open for days.

What is the output says? Is it possible your app is crashing?

Answer (score 1):

with Xcode 11.4+

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/3526064-executiontimeallowance

Also you can set it from test plan configuration

[image]